# pgfplot cannot read file

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make a figure but I get an error about cannot read file. 
    I made sure the dat file is in the directory with the `.tex` file and that the 
    spelling is correct. the error also suggest i use `row sep=crcr` and place `\\`
    at end of each line, but I'm not sure what to make of it. This is just a 
    fraction of the data to make it more manageable to troubleshoot.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}


    \begin{filecontents}{ST043-2.dat}
    nm 0 2.3 3.5 5.2 7.8 11.7 17.6 26.3 39.5 59.3 88.9 133.3 200 300
    384 0.133 0.154 0.156 0.159 0.154 0.152 0.149 0.142 0.14 0.139 0.146   0.173 0.192 0.226
    385 0.132 0.155 0.157 0.159 0.156 0.152 0.149 0.142 0.14 0.139 0.145 0.172 0.192 0.224
    386 0.135 0.156 0.158 0.16 0.158 0.153 0.149 0.142 0.139 0.14 0.144 0.17 0.191 0.223
    387 0.137 0.158 0.158 0.162 0.159 0.154 0.15 0.141 0.138 0.14 0.144 0.169 0.189 0.222
    388 0.137 0.159 0.159 0.162 0.161 0.155 0.15 0.14 0.139 0.14 0.144 0.17 0.188 0.223
    389 0.137 0.159 0.16 0.163 0.161 0.155 0.149 0.139 0.138 0.138 0.143 0.166 0.185 0.221
    390 0.141 0.162 0.162 0.165 0.162 0.155 0.15 0.141 0.138 0.137 0.143 0.164 0.185 0.219
    391 0.144 0.166 0.166 0.168 0.165 0.158 0.152 0.143 0.139 0.138 0.142 0.165 0.184 0.217
    392 0.15 0.17 0.171 0.171 0.168 0.161 0.154 0.144 0.14 0.14 0.142 0.166 0.185 0.216
    393 0.153 0.173 0.175 0.173 0.171 0.162 0.156 0.144 0.141 0.14 0.142 0.165 0.183 0.214
    394 0.157 0.177 0.179 0.178 0.175 0.166 0.159 0.146 0.142 0.141 0.143 0.165 0.182 0.213
    395 0.162 0.181 0.183 0.182 0.178 0.169 0.16 0.147 0.143 0.14 0.143 0.164 0.179 0.211
    396 0.169 0.187 0.188 0.187 0.182 0.173 0.162 0.148 0.144 0.141 0.142 0.164 0.179 0.211
    397 0.171 0.194 0.195 0.194 0.188 0.179 0.165 0.15 0.146 0.142 0.142 0.164 0.179 0.211
    398 0.182 0.201 0.202 0.2 0.195 0.184 0.168 0.152 0.148 0.143 0.143 0.163 0.179 0.21
    399 0.189 0.209 0.21 0.208 0.202 0.19 0.174 0.156 0.151 0.145 0.144 0.163 0.178 0.209
    400 0.199 0.219 0.22 0.218 0.21 0.198 0.181 0.16 0.154 0.149 0.147 0.163 0.178 0.209
    401 0.209 0.228 0.229 0.227 0.219 0.206 0.186 0.163 0.157 0.152 0.148 0.163 0.176 0.209
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{ST043-2.dat}{\ST043-2)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    Title={UV/VIS spectra of ST043-2},
    xlabel={nm},
    ylabel={Abs},
    xmin=385, xmax=550,
    xtick=50,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot [black,very thick,color=red] table [x={nm}, y={0}] {\ST043-2};
    \addplot [dashed,red,very thick,color=emerald] table [x={nm}, y={2.3}] {\ST043-2};
    \addplot [dashed,blue,very thick,color=apricot] table [x={nm}, y={3.5}] {\ST043-2};
    \addplot [dashed,red,very thick,color=emerald] table [x={nm}, y={5.2}] {\ST043-2};
    \addplot [dashed,red,very thick,color=olivegreen] table [x={nm}, y={7.8}] {\ST043-2};

     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't read the file is because the command `\ST043-2` is not parsed correctly.
My guess is that the hyphen `-` breaks the command.
If I replace all instances of `\ST043-2` with `\stear` as in the code below,
it compiles fine.
(I also deleted the color names because it wouldn't compile for me with the color names.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{filecontents}{ST043-2.dat}
nm 0 2.3 3.5 5.2 7.8 11.7 17.6 26.3 39.5 59.3 88.9 133.3 200 300
384 0.133 0.154 0.156 0.159 0.154 0.152 0.149 0.142 0.14 0.139 0.146   0.173 0.192 0.226
385 0.132 0.155 0.157 0.159 0.156 0.152 0.149 0.142 0.14 0.139 0.145 0.172 0.192 0.224
386 0.135 0.156 0.158 0.16 0.158 0.153 0.149 0.142 0.139 0.14 0.144 0.17 0.191 0.223
387 0.137 0.158 0.158 0.162 0.159 0.154 0.15 0.141 0.138 0.14 0.144 0.169 0.189 0.222
388 0.137 0.159 0.159 0.162 0.161 0.155 0.15 0.14 0.139 0.14 0.144 0.17 0.188 0.223
389 0.137 0.159 0.16 0.163 0.161 0.155 0.149 0.139 0.138 0.138 0.143 0.166 0.185 0.221
390 0.141 0.162 0.162 0.165 0.162 0.155 0.15 0.141 0.138 0.137 0.143 0.164 0.185 0.219
391 0.144 0.166 0.166 0.168 0.165 0.158 0.152 0.143 0.139 0.138 0.142 0.165 0.184 0.217
392 0.15 0.17 0.171 0.171 0.168 0.161 0.154 0.144 0.14 0.14 0.142 0.166 0.185 0.216
393 0.153 0.173 0.175 0.173 0.171 0.162 0.156 0.144 0.141 0.14 0.142 0.165 0.183 0.214
394 0.157 0.177 0.179 0.178 0.175 0.166 0.159 0.146 0.142 0.141 0.143 0.165 0.182 0.213
395 0.162 0.181 0.183 0.182 0.178 0.169 0.16 0.147 0.143 0.14 0.143 0.164 0.179 0.211
396 0.169 0.187 0.188 0.187 0.182 0.173 0.162 0.148 0.144 0.141 0.142 0.164 0.179 0.211
397 0.171 0.194 0.195 0.194 0.188 0.179 0.165 0.15 0.146 0.142 0.142 0.164 0.179 0.211
398 0.182 0.201 0.202 0.2 0.195 0.184 0.168 0.152 0.148 0.143 0.143 0.163 0.179 0.21
399 0.189 0.209 0.21 0.208 0.202 0.19 0.174 0.156 0.151 0.145 0.144 0.163 0.178 0.209
400 0.199 0.219 0.22 0.218 0.21 0.198 0.181 0.16 0.154 0.149 0.147 0.163 0.178 0.209
401 0.209 0.228 0.229 0.227 0.219 0.206 0.186 0.163 0.157 0.152 0.148 0.163 0.176 0.209
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{ST043-2.dat}{\stear}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[
title={UV/VIS spectra of ST043-2},
xlabel={nm},
ylabel={Abs},
xmin=385, xmax=550,
xtick=50,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot [black,very thick] table [x={nm}, y={0}] {\stear};
\addplot [dashed,red,very thick] table [x={nm}, y={2.3}] {\stear};
\addplot [dashed,blue,very thick] table [x={nm}, y={3.5}] {\stear};
\addplot [dashed,red,very thick] table [x={nm}, y={5.2}] {\stear};
\addplot [dashed,red,very thick] table [x={nm}, y={7.8}] {\stear};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: great! thanks for your help. does the filecontent section have to have space delimiters or can I use commas? bc the source of the csv by default outputs with comma delimiters and I have to remove all the commas and replace with spaces. thanks again!

Comment: @SpencerTrinh This is a good question but you should ask it as a separate question in order to get the attention that it deserves.